# How To Make A Song Play After Current One Ends Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm doing this discord bot and I'm trying to find out how to just continuously check if the song is playing and when it ends, check if there is a song in the queue, and if it is, play it if not, do nothing. I wanna know if there's like an event for when an audio ends? I have tried a while loop but that won't work.

```
AN EVENT FOR WHEN AUDIO STOPS PLAYING OR SOME LOOP:
    if len(queue):
        voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(f"{next(next_song)}.wav")
        voice.stop()
        voice.play(source)
        await ctx.send("Next Song Playing")
        queue.remove(source)
```